# How detect actual body and recipients of SMS with MFMessageComposeViewController for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, sms

From what I understand there is no way to send SMS from code for the iPhone.

Instead I am using the MFMessageComposeViewController to show the SMS application.
I set the body and recipients before:

```
MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
controller.body = @"message";
controller.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"phonenumber"];
controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

I want to make sure that the message and recipient stay untouched and remains the same as i set from code.
However it is possible for the user to change the recipients and/or the message before sending the SMS.

I tried checking the body and recipients in the delegate method

```
- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result {
 NSLog(@"Message: %@", controller.body);

 NSLog(@"Recipients:");
 for (NSString *recipient in controller.recipients) {
  NSLog(recipient);
 }
 switch (result) {
  case MessageComposeResultCancelled:
   NSLog(@"Result: canceled");
   break;
  case MessageComposeResultSent:
   NSLog(@"Result: sent");
   // Check that the correct message has been sent
   if([controller.body isEqualToString:correctMessage]) {
    BOOL correctRecipient = NO;
    for (NSString *recipient in controller.recipients) {
     if([recipient isEqualToString:correctRecipient]) {
      correctRecipient = YES;
     }
    }

    if(correctRecipient) {
     NSLog(@"Correct message sent to correct recipient!");
    } else {
     NSLog(@"Message or recipient was wrong");
    }
   }

   break;
  case MessageComposeResultFailed:
   NSLog(@"Result: failed");
   break;
  default:
   NSLog(@"Result: not sent");
   break;
 }

 [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

However, the controller.body and controller.recipients doesnt show the changes made in the SMS application. The documentation confirms this by saying that

*body: The initial content of the message.*
*recipients: An array of strings containing the initial recipients of the message.*

Is there any way to check the ACTUAL message and recipients that were used?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also it would be alright if it is possible to make the body / recipients nonchangable of course. But i doubt that this is possible?

Answer (score 3):

MailComposer behavior is also same like MessageComposer. We can initialize the contents and present, but we can't access any values after sent or after presenting the controller. -- No getter methods available